# Jest/Typescript: Mock class dependencies in Jest and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have class B which is dependent on class A. I want to test a method of class B which is internally calling a method of class A. Now, I want to unit test my method of class B by mocking class A.

My code structure:

```
class A {
  getSomething() {
     return "Something";
  }
}


class B {
  constructor(objectOfClassA: A) {
      this._objectOfClassA = objectOfClassA;

 }

 functionofClassBToTest() {
     const returnValueFromClassA = this._objectOfClassA.getSomething();

     return returnValueFromClassA;
 }
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
import ....
import { mocked } from 'jest-mock';

jest.mock("./A", () => {
    return {
        A: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                getSomething: getSomethingMock
            }
        })
    };
});

const getSomethingMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return "Mock value";
});

const mockA = mocked(A, true);

test("test functionofClassBToTest", () => {
    const classBToTest = new B(mockA);

    expect(classBToTest.functionofClassBToTest.toStrictEqual("Mock value");
});
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
TypeError: this._objectOfClassA.getSomething is not a function
```

Note: I don't want to initialize an object of class A inside my test function. I only want to mock the class.

I also found some previous posts on SO : [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445082/jest-mock-typescript-dependency) and [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759035/mock-dependency-in-jest-with-typescript) but nothing worked.

**UPDATE:** This problem got solved thanks to [James's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636159/418150). For mocking classes with private members, I have asked another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640035/jest-typescript-mock-class-dependencies-containing-private-members-in-jest-and). Please do read it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given that Typescript is *structurally typed*, it should be possible to simply construct an object literally that matches the interface of the A class and pass that into class B.

For example:

```
const mockA: jest.Mocked<A> = {
  getSomething: jest.fn()
};

const b = new B(mockA);

expect(mockA.getSomething)
    .toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This should not generate type errors given mockA exactly matches the interface of class A.

To mock the return value of A’s methods, refer to mocking individual functions with Jest.

This proves to be simpler and more succinct than attempting to mock the entire module. Since you’ve used IoC as a pattern, mocking the module is not necessary.

You also have a typo. Class B assigns to an instance variable with only one underscore but then calls the method on an instance variable with two underscores.

Comment: Thanks @james-dunne for your answer. It solved my problem. Just one thing to add here:

While creating the mockA I had to write it like this:

const mockA: jest.Mocked<A> = {
  getSomething: jest.fn()
};
Note: the typo was by mistake while writing the question in SO. Thanks.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer to reflect how you got it working, thank you :)