# Jest/Typescript: Mock class dependencies containing private members in jest and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Context : I have class B which is dependent on class A. I want to test a method of class B which is internally calling a method of class A. Now, I want to unit test my method of class B by mocking class A.

**Note 1**: **Class A has some private members**

**Note 2**: **Class A has no interface**

Here's my code structure:

```
class Base {

  someMethod() {
     return "Hello ";
  }

}


class A {

  private _baseClassImpl: Base;

  constructor(baseClassImpl: Base) {
     this._baseClassImpl = baseClassImpl;
  }

  getSomething() {     
     return this._baseClassImpl.someMethod() + " Something";
  }
}


class B {
  constructor(objectOfClassA: A) {
      this._objectOfClassA = objectOfClassA;

 }

 functionOfClassBToTest() {
     const returnValueFromClassA = this._objectOfClassA.getSomething();

     return returnValueFromClassA;
 }
}
```

What I have tried so far :

After taking suggestions from [my previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635377/jest-typescript-mock-class-dependencies-in-jest-and-typescript) I tried to write the tests like this:

```
const getSomethingMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return "Mock value";
});

const mockA = jest.Mocked<A> = {
   getSomething: getSomethingMock
};

test("test functionOfClassBToTest", () => {
   const classBToTest = new B(mockA);
   
   expect(classBToTest.functionofClassBToTest.toStrictEqual("Hello Something");

});
```

The above code gives me this error:

```
Type '{ getSomething: jest.Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable is not assignable to type 'Mocked<A>'. 
Type '{ getSomething: jest.Mock<any, any>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'A': _baseClassImpl
```

And When I try to provide the mock value for _baseClassImpl like this:

```
const baseClassMock = jest.Mocked<Base> = {
  someMethod: jest.fn()
};

const getSomethingMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return "Mock value";
});

const mockA = jest.Mocked<A> = {
   getSomething: getSomethingMock,
   _baseClassImpl: baseClassMock
};
```

Typescript gives me this error:

```
Type '{ getSomething: jest.Mock<any, any>; _baseClassImpl: jest.Mocked<Base>; }' is not assignable is not assignable to type 'Mocked<A>'. 

Type '{ getSomething: jest.Mock<any, any>; _baseClassImpl: jest.Mocked<Base>; }' is not assignable is not assignable to type 'A'. 

Property '_baseClassImpl' is private in type 'A' but not in type '{ getSomething: jest.Mock<any, any>; _baseClassImpl: jest.Mocked<Base>; }'
```

I have tried the answer on my [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635377/jest-typescript-mock-class-dependencies-in-jest-and-typescript) but it didn't work incase of class with private members.

Some notes:

**Note 1**: **Class A contains private member**

**Note 2**: **Class A has no interface**

**Note 3**: **I don't want to initialize an object of class A inside my test function. I only want to mock the class.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some hit & try and help of this [github repo](https://github.com/stevenulibarri/jest-typescript-mock-reference), I was able to resolve the issue.

Here's the code for reference:

Test for functionOfClassBToTest :

```
//Note: this can be also written as : const mockA = new (<any>A)() as jest.Mocked<A>;
const mockA = new (<new () => A>A)() as jest.Mocked<A>;

mockA.getSomething = jest.fn();

test("test functionOfClassBToTest", () => {
   
   mockA.getSomething.mockReturnValueOnce("Hello Something");

   const classBToTest = new B(mockA);
   
   expect(classBToTest.functionofClassBToTest.toStrictEqual("Hello Something");

});
```

Comment: This answer is very helpful! What would you do if there were several functions in mockA? For example, if functionofClassBToTest called 5-6 different functions in mockA, would you have to define all of those (e.g. mockA.getSomethingElse = jest.fn();).

Comment: Thank you! This saved me a lot of time!

Comment: How to make this work if you have object destructuring in the constructor's parameters?